# Connector creation for ServiceNow

Tags: connector, servicenow

How to develop a connector in java to create user, and get the services of ServiceNow. Is there any API which support java. I want to develop the connector using java. please help. I am trying from long days.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "a connector" but to interact with a ServiceNow instance from another system/app you can use Web Services. You could use ServiceNow's REST API (table or import set) to interact with users (create, query, update, delete).

Check out ServiceNow's REST API Documentation and Java sample code. Including links below.

**Docs**
- [REST API Overview](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=REST_API) 
- [REST Table API](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API)
- [Java Examples](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API_Java_Examples#GET)

Comment: If you are using WSO2 ESB you can easily integrate with service now using the connector. Internally connector is using the rest api of service now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a connector in wso2 store for serviceNow Rest API. You can use it with WSO2 ESB. Here is the link of WSO2 Store. https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/74999163-6706-41f6-a564-61479b99918f

Answer (score 0):

When calling rest service from java you can use HTTPConnectionURL or Apache Http client. You can find samples in [1] and more info in [2]

If your requirement is very simple you can simple do this with a point to point integrations using a java client. If your integration requirements will grow in future and need well defined archtecture have a integration platform. If you decide to use [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) you can easily integrate with service now using ready made [service now connector.](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/74999163-6706-41f6-a564-61479b99918f)

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-integration-base/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/connector/integration/test/base/ConnectorIntegrationTestBase.java

[2] [RESTful call in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913502/restful-call-in-java)