# Which API is meant by "the Web API"?

Tags: java, django, web-services, rest, jax-rs

How do I invoke "the Web API" for the [nasearch site](http://search.nashownotes.com/) with Java?  Also, this [github repo](https://github.com/lifenoodles/nasearch) is a Django project?  If so, is there a special way to invoke the "Web API" with Java?

The [readme](https://github.com/lifenoodles/nasearch) says:

> You can use the Web API to fetch a list of existing topics, conduct
>   searches, or pull shownotes by episode.

That would be with jax-rs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should make a REST call to the web API for Nasearch.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913502/restful-call-in-java) for how to do this in Java. As per the readme you can connect to "/api/topics" for example.

Comment: Are there other types of calls which I could make, in this case?  How would I know?

Comment: @Thufir Probably not. The call/request that you make to the API will respond with the data that you need.