# Using Microsoft Project Oxford APIs in Java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I already looked it up, and i found that I can load the API through a .dll file. But I keep thinking i'm overcomplicating everything... Is there an easier way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are just regular REST api's, so the question is really 'how do I call a rest api in Java?' I'm not a Java dev so cannot answer, but this SO thread looks like it could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913502/restful-call-in-java. I wrote a blog on how to do it in C# and JavaScript if that helps? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martinkearn/archive/2016/03/07/using-the-project-oxford-emotion-api-in-c-and-javascript.aspx

Comment: Thank you for answering. The thread you sent was very helpfull

Comment: have to tried the Microsoft Project Oxford ?

Comment: I have gone through some of the docs, and what i found that the congnitive Services Speaker Recognnition is not Speech Recognizer?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [Cognitive Services Client Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/) for Android, because it takes care of all complications for you. In case you are doing plain Java and not Android, I believe the code should be pretty much portable.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).