# Importing API into my java program

Tags: java, api, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebAPIs, and I was asked to acquire the longitude and latitude of a specific location with the help of a certain website's APIs. (website deleted), and I was provided with an asset key as well.
I think my question here is, how do I import this API into my program in Java?

Comment: I just quickly glanced at the link, but this looks like a RESTful web service. The question here addresses how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913502/restful-call-in-java

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Thank you very much, the link is very helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of Assets query from that page using the provided demo key:

> EXAMPLE QUERY
>
> https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY

[this is in Java 6, modify to suit your Java version]

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NasaRestAPIExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String query = "lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY";

        URLConnection connection = new URL("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?" + query).openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader r  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

output:

```
{"count": 61, "results": [{"date": "2014-02-04T03:30:01", "id": "LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014035LGN00"}, ...
```

Comment: This is not a solution. It's hard-coding a single query and getting a single result. Well established and robust REST Java libraries exist that should be preferred.

Comment: I just provided an example of what the OP asked. If it is not considered a solution, why did the OP accept it as an answer?

Comment: Fair point. I don't think the OP knew what they wanted, though.

Comment: If this answer didn't serve their purpose, they shouldn't have accepted it. If you can provide a *real* solution, I will gladly delete my answer, if possible.

Comment: I could write a _real_ solution easily, but I won't. I won't do someone else's work/homework on a trivial problem, but have no problem helping/pointing in the right direction. You or I may have to work with this person in the future, so it's best they try to figure it out themselves. I apologize if you were offended; that wasn't my intent.

Comment: I respect and appreciate you sharing that. no offense taken, I learn too, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I took this answer because I felt it help me understand what I am trying to do. Maybe I shouldn't accept it as answer because it didn't "actually answer" my question.

Comment: Yes, if we can remove and delete it, is probably best, sorry if I suggested something inappropriate.

Comment: @downshift I really appreciate your help. I was lost and I think your suggestion is very helpful. This is why I accepted an answer instead of waiting for more people to "do my homework" for me.

Comment: No worries, I don't understand the protocol sometimes. If you can unaccept this answer, I tried to delete it, but it says "you can't delete an accepted answer".