# How can I make a Http Post request to external Rest API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-http-client

i am new in Java spring Framework ,
i need a way to call from my application an external Rest API.
Is there any 'best practice' http client so I can use for my need?

Comment: [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) maybe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365266/call-another-rest-api-from-my-server-in-spring-boot

Comment: [This tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) should help.

Comment: Please, do some google work, before asking any question to the community. For example, you can search for: "spring perform post request" in google and you definitely will find some great answer on SF.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+resttemplate = 336.000 results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call another rest api from my server in Spring-Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365266/call-another-rest-api-from-my-server-in-spring-boot)

Comment: use RestTemplate provided by spring itself it will improve your application performance as well

Answer (score 5):

Use RestTemplate:

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {
   @Autowired
   RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/sample/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String createProducts(@RequestBody SampleClass sampleClass) {
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      HttpEntity<SampleClass> entity = new HttpEntity<SampleClass>(sampleClass,headers);

      return restTemplate.exchange(
         "https://example.com/endpoint", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to always add imports to solutions like these.