# Calling an endpoint inside of a class in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an endpoint that I need to call from a method inside of a class.

```
public void remove(String str) {
    //Call Controller with str
}
```

The controller has `/local/{str}`. How do I call this controller from that method?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html and https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365266/call-another-rest-api-from-my-server-in-spring-boot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call another rest api from my server in Spring-Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365266/call-another-rest-api-from-my-server-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I suppose that your controller is similar to this

```
@GetMapping("/local/{str}")
public String method(@PathVariable String str) {...}
```

Why not to call this method directly?

```
public void remove(String str) {
    method("my parameter");
}
```

Or you can also call this endpoint by using `RestTemplate`

```
public void remove(String str) {
    final String uri = "http://hostName/local/{str}";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("str", "my_String");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String response = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class, params);
}
```