# Tools in Java/Spring to interact with a Restful API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-method

I'm building a Java application that needs to access an external Restful API.

I need to perform POST, GET and PUT on this API.

In PHP I used curl and in C# I used HTTPClient.

Which tool should I use in Java/Spring? I'm new in Java and I'm kind lost.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call another rest api from my server in Spring-Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365266/call-another-rest-api-from-my-server-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)  as Spring's way of sending HTTP methods

> RestTemplate offers **templates for common scenarios by HTTP method**, in addition to the generalized exchange and execute methods that support of less frequent cases

Here are [examples](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/) of using GET/ POST/ PUT methods

Comment: In the provided link they said that RestTemplate is going to be depricated in behalf of WebClient so I'll go directly to WebClient.