# Spring boot reactive and GraalVM java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientSecure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

When I'm creating a native image using Spring reactive and WebClient everything ends correctly but when I'm making a request using the WebClient, I get this error given below :

```
2021-01-10 04:10:22.904 ERROR 1 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [id: 0x3dd90c0b, L:/172.17.0.2:8080 - R:/172.17.0.1:48222]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientSecure
        at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:215) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:211) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:76) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:263) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:83) ~[na:na]
```

This is my code

```
public Flux<User> getAllUser() {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/v1/07defb0d")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(User.class);
    }
```

[This is my full example code](https://github.com/dberna2/spring-boot-graalvm.git)

Any suggestion for me?

Comment: i would suggest you start by upgrading the `spring-graalvm-native` to the latest version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webclient maven Dependency errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730276/webclient-maven-dependency-errors)