# Call another rest api from my server in Ktor

Tags: rest, kotlin, intellij-idea, backend, ktor

I want to call another web-api from my backend on a specific request of user.

How can I achieve this in Ktor. Like in spring boot we use Rest Template, but how can I do the same in Ktor.

Reference Article for doing the same in spring boot: ([Call another rest api from my server in Spring-Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365266/call-another-rest-api-from-my-server-in-spring-boot))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ktor http client

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO)
val response: HttpResponse = client.get("https://ktor.io/")
println(response.status)
client.close()
```

[Making HTTP requests in ktor](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTTP client like Unirest to make the call to the other web api

```
Unirest.get("https://reqres.in/api/users/1").asString();
```

https://kong.github.io/unirest-java/