# How would I query a REST API with a Bukkit plugin?

Tags: java, rest, minecraft, bukkit

I seem to be having some trouble querying a REST API from within a Minecraft Bukkit plugin. Any tips on how this could be possible?
I'm trying to use REST assured but haven't found luck.

Am new to java/bukkit development and this is my first time trying to query a REST API.

```
    [08:03:34 ERROR]: [global] TaskChain Exception on io.paradaux.report.cmds.ReportCMD$$Lambda$3940/1841602366: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/RestAssured
[08:03:34 ERROR]: [global] Current Action Index was: 0
[08:03:34 WARN]: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/RestAssured
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at co.aikar.taskchain.TaskChain.handleError(TaskChain.java:1203)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at co.aikar.taskchain.TaskChain.access$600(TaskChain.java:57)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at co.aikar.taskchain.TaskChain$TaskHolder.run(TaskChain.java:1320)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at co.aikar.taskchain.TaskChain$TaskHolder.access$100(TaskChain.java:1266)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at co.aikar.taskchain.TaskChain.lambda$nextTask$18(TaskChain.java:1187)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/RestAssured
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at io.paradaux.report.api.BugReport.sendWebhook(BugReport.java:73)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at io.paradaux.report.api.BugReport.execute(BugReport.java:85)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at io.paradaux.report.cmds.ReportCMD.lambda$onCommand$0(ReportCMD.java:64)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at co.aikar.taskchain.TaskChainTasks$GenericTask.run(TaskChainTasks.java:83)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at co.aikar.taskchain.TaskChain$TaskHolder.run(TaskChain.java:1312)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    ... 7 more
[08:03:34 WARN]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.restassured.RestAssured
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:182)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:111)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[08:03:34 WARN]:    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RESTful call in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913502/restful-call-in-java)

Comment: Hint: here's the important part of your error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.restassured.RestAssured`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `io.restassured.RestAssured` is not on your class path. You should compile any library your'e using into your jar file, when it is not given by any other plugin or by Bukkit itself.