# Is there a way to get totalSupply of an ERC20 token using web3j java?

Tags: android, erc20, web3-java

I'm developing an android app using android studio. I implemented web3j and successfully connected to ethereum using infura. I'm not sure how I can get the total supply of a specific coin.

Tried using the load method to load a specific tokens contract but was not able to get that to work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using RPC nodes like Infura, I recommend that you use Moralis as it provides you with an easy API that you can call in Java. It's a basic REST API so you can call it in any other language too.

You can use this [`runContractFunction`](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/reference/run-contract-function) API here. And all you need to do is provide the input parameters as follows:

- `address`: ERC20 token contract address
- `chain`: the chain your ERC20 token exists
- `function_name`: `totalSupply`
- `abi`: the ABI of ERC20 token

Once you have all this setup, you'll be able to get the total supply in just a few lines of code.

Hope this helps out! :

Comment: I entered in all the info with the runContractFunction link you provided and im getting this error message "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inputs'), Function `totalSupply` not found in ABI"?

Comment: Also, is there an example with Java calling Moralis API? Not sure how I would go about doing that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure in Java, not familiar with the language entirely, you can check out the post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913502/restful-call-in-java

For the page, looks like there's been a bug in docs since I was able to execute the function myself. I'll report this to Moralis.